# Bytes IO and Text Files

Tags: bytesio

This may come as a silly question but it would really help me clear my concepts.
Bytes IO utilizes bytes string which means it uses bytes data.
And bytes data is not human readable.

So when I code the following:

```
f = open('new.txt','wb')
f.write(b'helloworld')
f.close()
```

A txt file appears in the python rote directory and when I open it, the text 'hello world' is present in it. My question is that I coded bytes data. Why am I able to read it in a text file as 'hello world' when bytes data is only computer readable.

Comment: Oddly enough, the bytes that make up ascii characters are the characters themselves when viewed as text.

Comment: Shouldn't it have displayed the text as b'Hello world' in the txt file?

Comment: No. It isn't a "text" file, and the `b` just signifies it is binary data when you interact with it in memory. The file just contains the bytes, as-is. The misconception is that binary data is not human readable.If you instead displayed the bytes as integers you might not recognize 104 as 'h', but when displayed as text that's just what it is. Files don't have an identity as binary or text either, it is all in how you interpret the data. On operating systems other than Windows opening a file as text or binary is the same thing. On Windows it just means the end of line character is translated.